# Issues while running tutorials of Drake programs, in Underactuated Robotics document, in Deepnote?

Tags: simulation, drake, pendulum, deepnote

I am trying to build and simulate a pendulum in drake. I have created a urdf file(still don't know how to add the inertia tags) and am trying to simulate it, but I don't know how to? So, I was looking at the simple pendulum tutorial in https://underactuated.mit.edu/pend.html. But when I tried to run this on deepnote I get the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'underactuated'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-e0ee1253693a> in <module>
     24                                        PendulumPlant)
     25 
---> 26 from underactuated import plot_2d_phase_portrait, running_as_notebook
     27 from underactuated.meshcat_cpp_utils import MeshcatSliders, interact
     28 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'underactuated'
```

How am I supposed to resolve this issue? Also, if you can recommend some resources that help me easily buid urdf files that would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Deepnote notebooks for the course use a docker instance which is provisioned with pydrake and underactuated.  You can duplicate one of our notebooks, or add the docker instance in the deepnote configuration yourself.  http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/drake.html#notebooks

We have another tutorial that will be polished and available soon in Drake for constructing the urdfs.  You can preview it here: https://deepnote.com/project/Authoring-a-Multibody-Simulation-jnoKyVLkS5CYUgHG3ASsBA/%2Fauthor_multibody_sim.ipynb (but know that it should be considered a draft).